# Array elements are shown twice

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

I have this card with double column styling that is supposed to show the first element of the array on the left, second on the right, third on the left below first and so on ... something like this:

[image]

So for the above example the array is something like:
`[{"Application": "BP 3ALT"}, {"Status:", "Issued permit"}, {"Address:", "4367"}, ... ]`

I have written this peice of code in Vuejs that accept the array as a prop but it shows each element twice on the website. Like if I pass `[{"Application:", "128 palmstreet"}]` you would see it on the first row twice like:

[image]

Even tho it should only appear once on the left. This is my code:

columnCard.vue:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" v-for="objData in data" :key="objData.label">
        <div class="line col-2">{{objData.label}}</div>
        <div class="line col-3 ">{{objData.value}}</div>
        <div class="vl"></div>
        <div class="line col-2 ">{{objData.label}}</div>
        <div class="line col-3 ">{{objData.value}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    props: {
      data: {
        type: Array
      }
    }
```

And the array that is passed on is: `[{'label': 'Application:', 'value': '128 palmstreet'}]`

UPDATE:
How can I fix it in a way that each object in the array is shown only once while conserving the style of double columns? deleting the two divs after `<div class="vl"></div>` messes up the styling, it removes the right column. We want to keep that.

Comment: You have `objData.label` and `objData.value` twice in the html clearly .. what other output are you expecting?

Comment: That is true. But I need the styling to be like that (double column) The output is what you see on the first picture. we want to only show label and value.

Answer (score 0):

You have the elements repeated in the templated. Like this they won't be repeated

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row" v-for="objData in data" :key="objData.label">
        <div class="line col-2">{{objData.label}}</div>
        <div class="line col-3 ">{{objData.value}}</div>
        <div class="vl"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

    props: {
      data: {
        type: Array
      }
    }
```

Comment: if we do that the it wont show the output on the right column. We want to see the first element on the left, second on the right, third on the bottom of the first one on the left and so on..

Comment: Your question is; why they are twice. My answer is the solution to that question.